# Can't retain numberformat after using Indirect to copy cells between worksheets

Tags: excel-formula, number-formatting, excel-indirect

I have used indirect function to copy cells between worksheets which works fine but i do not get the same number format (as i am getting same values to different decimal places). Can some one please suggest the way around this. My source cell has 3 decimal places but after copying with indirect formula it is only 1 decimal place. My formula is "=INDIRECT(B2)&""!C1"")"  where B2 is sheet name and C1 is cell to copy from B2 sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect can retain the decimal points. Perhaps you're just visually seeing them as such. You can expand the decimal places by clicking the "Increase decimal" button in your ribbon:

[image]